# A guide on using integration by substitution.

Tags: integration, online-resources

Integration by substitution is a tricky thing to master, I'm learning it from books and at some place my book has done something like this

> $$\int \csc\theta \cot\theta \; d\theta = ?$$
>   $$ \int \frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta} \;d\theta$$
>   Let $u = \sin\theta$, $du = \cos\theta \;d\theta$
>   $$\int u^{-2} \;du$$
>   $$ -1/u = -1/\sin\theta = -\csc\theta$$

But it was very apparent that the integral was one of the standard one and using the substitution rule was redundant (it may that book wanted to show me the power of substitution rule).

I need some personal notes or something which you have made for your lectures or some personal real-life *discovery* about using the substitution rule in integration. I know this is an easy thing to master if some experienced man helps me.

Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that math is not a "spectator sport", you need to make an effort and "play". You already got some books as I understand so go ahead and do exercises, of course you don't need to use the methods you see there, do it your way if you find something better. If you don't like those books you can find here on MSE hundreds of interesting integrals. I would also recommend those [notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/IntegralsIntro.aspx).

Comment: How do you think that result *got* to be standard?

Comment: @J.G. That’s something we learn before being introduced to substitution.